# What do I select to get the free trial in Windows Azure Dashboard?

Tags: azure

I am hoping to use Windows Azure for an internal application at work. I have signed up, and hoping to take advantage of the FREE 90 day trial to see if it offers what we need.

So my question is, on the dashboard what do I need to select to get the free trial?

I do not want to select something which ends up costing us, while we are just looking into the possibility of using it. Or do I just what services we need and they are taken from the trial allowance?

Answer (score 0):

You do whatever services you need and they are taken from the trial allowance.

If you hit the trial allowance all your services will be deleted, but the data in storage account will be kept. You will not be able to do anything until the next billing cycle begins.

When you create a trial by default it has "[SPENDING LIMIT](http://www.windowsazure.com/en-us/pricing/spending-limits/)", be sure NOT TO REMOVE IT, if you do not want charges.